# Create laravel configuration file apache web server

Tags: apache2, laravel-4, webserver

to delete the public folder from my url I have seen that I have to edit the apache configuration file, but since I also have projects that are not developed with laravel I saw that there is the possibility to create a custom configuration file. Where should I put this file?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a virtual host to serve as your laravel project like below. 
Just edit your Apache's httpd-vhosts.conf file and add something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project-laravel
    DocumentRoot "YOURPATH/apache2/htdocs/project-laravel/public"
    <Directory "YOURPATH/apache2/htdocs/project-laravel/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also you would have to edit your hosts file and add a line 
127.0.0.1 project-laravel

Then, restart Apache and enter the project-laravel into your browser bar.

Comment: But where I find the Apache's httpd-vhosts.conf file? I don't find it in apache2/sites-enabled ..

Comment: Should be in Apache2/conf/extra directory. Is this Windows environent ? There is also a httpd.conf file, where there is a line: Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf - make sure that line is not commented (does not begin with #)

Comment: It is ad ubuntu 13.10 enviroment